# SEO user friendly url using Pretty faces and spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jsf, prettyfaces

I have followed [this](https://dzone.com/articles/developing-jsf-applications-with-spring-boot) to configure spring boot work with JSF and the configuration is ok however I need to get rid of .xhtml suffix in all my jsf using pretty faces. I have so far managed to configure PrettyFaces RewriteFilter in my spring boot and added the URLMapping in my managed bean but it doesnt seem to work am getting '**Whitelabel Error Page**'. Here is my login managed bean

```
@Scope(value = "session")
@Component(value = "loginMgr")
@URLMapping(id = "login",
        pattern = "/login",
        viewId = "/my_context/login.xhtml")
public class LoginManager {

}
```

and my pretty faces configuration bean

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean prettyFilter() {
    System.out.println("pretty filter called");
    RewriteFilter filter=new RewriteFilter();
    FilterRegistrationBean prettyFilter = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    prettyFilter.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.REQUEST,
            DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.ERROR);
    prettyFilter.addUrlPatterns("/*");

    return prettyFilter;
}
```

and this is my sping boot application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
#spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
server.context-path=/my_context
spring.security.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false
security.basic.enabled=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrateg
```

I am using jsf 2.2 and primefaces 5.3 and below are the pretty faces maven dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-integration-faces</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

and this 
[image: this]is the error am getting

Comment: @BalusC If I use normal JSF without spring boot your solution in the above links works well but my problem is how to put the same in spring boot

Comment: @BalusC yes as per your correction normal JEE works fine but spring boot is the issue

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to get rid of the .xhtml suffix and use MyFaces 2.3, you can simply set:
`org.apache.myfaces.AUTOMATIC_EXTENSIONLESS_MAPPING` to `true`.

So you dont need PrettyFaces or Rewrite.

NOTE:
it might throw a exception that `#getServletRegistrations` can't be called from a Listener not configured in `web.xml` or `web-fragment.xml`.
In this case you need to add `org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener` to your `web.xml` or `web-fragment.xml`..

Comment: I am using annotation to configure jsf am not using web.xml

Comment: Just try it.... It should work OOTB, you just need to set `org.apache.myfaces.AUTOMATIC_EXTENSIONLESS_MAPPING`.
I just give you a hint if something doesnt work.

Comment: this is the error am getting org.apache.myfaces.ee6 does not exist

Comment: Post the whole stacktrace. Do you have both MyFaces API+IMPL in 2.3?

Comment: sorry for late reply here is the error https://pastebin.com/8RUTb3d8

Comment: and this is the log after adding the enterprise dependency https://pastebin.com/XzDMs9st